# code runs else statement repeatedly

Tags: python

every time the below code runs, it goes straight through to the first else statement, then runs the next else statement four times.  what is going on and how do I fix it so it calls the movement() module?

```
class square(object):
    def __init__(self,updown,leftright,residence,name):
        self.updown = updown
        self.leftright = leftright
        self.residence = bool
        self.name = name

    a1 = square(1,1,True,"a1")
    a2 = square(2,1,False,"a2")
    b1 = square(1,2,False,"b1")
    b2 = square(2,2,False,"b2")

    square_dict = {a1:"a1",a2:"a2",b1:"b1",b2:"b2"}
    movement_select()

 def movement_select():
    response = raw_input("where would you like to move?")
    if response in square_dict:
        moveTo = square_dict[response]
    else:
        print "this runs once"
    for a in square_dict:
        if a.residence == True:
            moveFrom = a
            movement(moveFrom,moveTo)
        else:
            print "this runs four times"
movement_select()
```

Comment: You have no `else` statement...

Comment: There are no `else` statements in your code.

Comment: Funny thing is that I can't find the word `else` in your code :D

Comment: sorry, I copy pasted an earlier version...

Comment: Could you fix your intendation? Because this way the code won't run, and I can't be sure I'm interpreting everything right if I fix it myself.

Answer (score 3):

Look at how you're defining `residence`:

```
    self.residence = bool
```

So, for any square `a`, `a.residence` will be the type `bool`, never the boolean value `True` (or anything else). So this test will always fail:

```
    if a.residence == True:
```

---

To fix it, change that first line to:

```
    self.residence = residence
```

While we're at it, you rarely need `== True`, so you can also change the second line to:

```
    if a.residence:
```

But that isn't a necessary fix, just a way of simplifying your code a bit.

---

Meanwhile, your `squares_dict` is a bit odd. I'm not sure whether it's incorrect or not, but let's take a look:

It maps from `square` objects to their names. That could be a useful thing to do. It means you can iterate over the dict and get all the `square`s—as you correctly do in your code. And if you later had a `square` and wanted to get its name, you could use `square_dict` for that. Then again, you could probably get the same benefit with just a `square_list`, and using the name already available as an attribute of the `square` objects (unless you need the same `square` to have different names in different contexts).

And meanwhile, a mapping in this direction can't be used for looking up `squares_dict[response]`, because `response` is a name, not a `square`. So, you definitely need a mapping in the opposite direction, either in addition to or instead of this one.

If you scrap the square-to-name mapping and only keep the name-to-square mapping, you can still iterate over the squares; you'd just have to do `for square in squares_dict.values():` instead of just `for square in squares_dict:`.

Comment: Just a side note: I personally try to avoid the "if variable" syntax as debugging will become a pain later on. Let's say a = "False", then "if a:" will be True.

Comment: @RyanG: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) explicitly says "Don't compare boolean values to `True` or `False` using `==`." It then shows `if greeting:` as right and `if greeting == True` as wrong. The reason is that, to avoid a very rare error, you're creating a very common error—many functions, including much of the stdlib, just return "something truthy", and if you check that with `== True`, you will do the wrong thing. Very few functions return something like the strings `"True"` and `"False"` unless they're horribly broken.

Answer (score 3):

**First problem**: your dictionary appears to be backwards: you want to look up the `square` objects from their locations, rather than the other way around. This is why your first conditional is never true. You also might as well `strip()` the `response` to ensure that you don't have any hidden whitespace in there.

```
square_dict = {"a1":a1, "a2":a2, "b1":b1, "b2":b2}
# Later...
response = raw_input("where would you like to move?").strip()
# Later still...
for a in square_dict.values(): # Because we switched the dictionary around!
```

If you don't want to silently strip off the whitespace, I'd suggest that you at least echo their input back to them (`print('"{}"'.format(response))`) in the case that it's not found in your dictionary, so they (you) can be sure that at least the input was correct.

---

The **second problem** is because of how you define `residence`. You set the variable equal to `bool`, which is not what you want at all. Line five ought to read:

```
self.residence = residence
```

---

Finally, some other thoughts on your code! You check whether a value is `True` by checking `if a.residence == True:`. The [preferred form](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) of this comparison is the simpler version:

```
if a.residence:
```

Your methods could also be named more descriptively. Generally speaking, it's always nice to begin a function or method name with a verb, to improve readability. This is of course a question of style, but for instance, the two functions we see, `movement_select` and `movement` aren't extremely clear as to their function. It would be much easier to read if they used a standardized form, e.g. `choose_move` and `perform_move`.

Comment: `raw_input` shouldn't leave a trailing newline?

Comment: @Noctua No, it doesn't. Never trust your users, though. ;-)

Comment: Then also strip "string.punctuation" and everything else that isn't a1,a2,b1,b2 :)

Comment: Users are indeed never to be trusted. Which is exactly why you shouldn't be so friendly and help them with their whitespace problems :P Crash that program on wrong input, I say.

Comment: @Noctua: Agreed, in most apps it's better to give them an error that helps them spot their problem than to try to guess what they mean. Just show the response inside quotes so they can see the spaces, or even try to diagnose it, but don't try to silently fix it. (Like password dialogs—if your caps lock is on, they warn you "Hey, your caps lock is on", but they don't switch to case-insensitive password lookups.)

Comment: @Noctua Fair enough; and abarnert's comment gives some good examples--though I think in this asker's situation, silently fixing whitespace problems is likely to be sufficient ;-)

Comment: @HenryKeiter It's a good answer, yes. I just didn't want anyone to think the strip was obligatory for a newline, as was said in another answer. ;-)

Comment: @Noctua Absolutely; I went ahead and added a disclaimer to that effect.

Comment: A minor quibble: Great point on the names, but if you're going to go with `perform_movement` instead of just `move` for the second verb, might as well go with `choose_movement` (or `select_movement`) for the second to keep them parallel.

Answer (score 2):

```
self.residence = bool
```

should be

```
self.residence = residence
```

Answer (score 1):

You don´t set residence right, this is wrong:

```
class square(object):
    def __init__(self,updown,leftright,residence,name):
        self.updown = updown
        self.leftright = leftright
        self.residence = bool
        self.name = name
```

it has to be

```
class square(object):
    def __init__(self,updown,leftright,residence,name):
        self.updown = updown
        self.leftright = leftright
        self.residence = residence  # not bool!!
        self.name = name
```

Answer (score -2):

Your response contains *\n* symbol, just **strip()** it
You should also swap places between keys and values in your dictionary

Comment: No, `raw_input` does not return a newline. And even if it did, there's no way that would affect the second `if/else` and prevent `movement` from being called.

Comment: @abarnert, maybe I am wrong with _strip_ - I never use UI in my code, maybe GUI sometimes. But it would not hurt. As about the second suggestion - without it the code still will end up in _else_ clause of the first _if_. I did not analyze code beyond that

Comment: OK, so you gave the wrong answer to the first part, and didn't even try to answer the second part, which he explicitly asked about…

Comment: Actually, I gave absolutely right answer (strip excluded) to the first part of the problem.